# Evade database errors in concurrent requests (PHP and Symfony)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a server API rest with PHP 7.1 and Symfony 3.2. I have a request that checks if a user has a draft, and if he does not have it, the draft it's created. The problem occurs when the same user makes two concurrent requests. Both requests pass the validation and see that the user does not have a draft. When the first arrives creates the draft, the one that arrives later tries to create it and throws a doctrine exception.

```
[Exception]: Doctrine \ DBAL \ Exception \ UniqueConstraintViolationException

[message]: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ChecklistDraft (id, title, description, estimated_time, creator_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)' with params [101, null, null, null, 50121] :
SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '50121' for key 'UNIQ_910CB4B461220EA6' .

[file]: /project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php .
```

The server returns a 500, which should not happen. I could control the exception in all requests but if in another request I make the code wrong and the exception is throwed I am not notified.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) explain how to handle this.

I think the best way for you is to create a doctrine transaction and catch only your `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException` not `\Exception` like this :

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    //... do some work
    $em->persist($draft);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
}
```

When you catch `\Exception` class without throw again the exception object after the rollback you can hide other issues that become hard to find and this can cause also others issues (like when you test your code with PHPSpec and when the PHPSPec exceptions are catched by your code)